Update a list of items and related many to many entities takes too much time with Entity Framework Core
I'm having an issue while trying to update a list of items having many to many relationship using Entity Framework Core.
I have for now two classes DeviceModel and DetectedAppModel with a many-to-many relationship :
public class DeviceModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? DeviceName { get; set; }
    public IList<DetectedAppModel> Apps { get; set; }

    public DeviceModel()
    {
         Apps = new List<DetectedAppModel>();
         // Users = new List<UserModel>();
         // Groups = new List<GroupModel>();
    }
}

public class DetectedAppModel
{
    [Required]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string? version { get; set; }
    public string? publisher { get; set; }
    public string? platform { get; set; }

    public IList<DeviceModel> Devices { get; set; }

    public DetectedAppModel(string _id, string _displayName) 
    {
        id = _id;
        displayName = _displayName;
        Devices = new List<DeviceModel>();
    }
}

I plan to periodically export a great number of devices and all their detected apps from a repository to load it into a SQL database. I have approx 25000 device and each of them can have hundreds of applications.
I tried so far to implement the following code, but I have terrible performance - last attempt took 12 hours until my computer lost connection to the DB and screwed everything without even getting to the save context part.
var devicelist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeviceModel>>(_DeviceyJson);

_logger.LogInformation("Get devices in db");

// Retrieve the current list of devices from the database
var dbDevices = _context.Devices
                        .Include(d => d.Apps)
                        .ToList();

// Create a dictionary for quick lookups
var dbDevicesDictionary = dbDevices.ToDictionary(d => d.Id);

// Find new devices that are not in the database
_logger.LogInformation("Iterate over devices");

foreach (var device in devicelist)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Processing " + device.DeviceName);

    if (dbDevicesDictionary.TryGetValue(device.Id, out var dbDevice))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(device.DeviceName + " exists, checking changes");
        // Check if the main properties of the device have changed
        bool deviceChanged = !AreDevicePropertiesEqual(device, dbDevice);

        // Check if the related Apps have changed
        bool appsChanged = !AreCollectionsEqual(device.Apps, dbDevice.Apps, app => app.id);

        // If nothing has changed, skip this device
        if (!deviceChanged && !appsChanged)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"No changes detected for device {device.DeviceName}. Skipping update.");
            continue;
        }

        // Update existing device
        _context.Entry(dbDevice).CurrentValues.SetValues(device);

        // Synchronize Apps
        // Find apps to remove
        if (!appsChanged)
        {
            HashSet<string> dbDeviceAppsIds = new HashSet<string>(dbDevice.Apps.Select(a => a.id));

            var appsToRemoveIds = dbDeviceAppsIds.Except(device.Apps.Select(a => a.id)).ToList();

            foreach (var appIdToRemove in appsToRemoveIds)
            {
                var appToRemove = dbDevice.Apps.First(a => a.id == appIdToRemove);
                _logger.LogInformation("Remove " + appToRemove.displayName + " from " + dbDevice.DeviceName);
                dbDevice.Apps.Remove(appToRemove);
            }

            // Find apps to add
            foreach (var newApp in device.Apps)
            {
                if (!dbDevice.Apps.Any(a => a.id == newApp.id))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("check if app " + newApp.displayName + " is tracked");

                    // Check if the app is already being tracked by the context
                    var trackedApp = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<DetectedAppModel>()
                                         .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Entity.id == newApp.id)?.Entity;

                    // If the app is not being tracked, add the new app
                    if (trackedApp == null)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Aapp " + newApp.displayName + " is not tracked");
                        dbDevice.Apps.Add(newApp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If the app is already being tracked, you can update the tracked entity if needed
                        // _context.Entry(trackedApp).CurrentValues.SetValues(newApp);
                        // Or simply use the tracked entity
                        _logger.LogInformation("App " + newApp.displayName + " is tracked");
                        dbDevice.Apps.Add(trackedApp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Add new device, including related apps
        try
        { 
            // Before adding the new device, ensure its apps are either attached or new
            _logger.LogInformation(device.DeviceName + " is new");

            foreach (var app in device.Apps.ToList()) // Use ToList to avoid modifying the collection while iterating
            {
                var existingApp = _context.DetectedApps.Local.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == app.id) // Check local (in-memory) cache
                        ?? await _context.DetectedApps.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.id == app.id); // Check the database

                if (existingApp != null)
                {
                    // If the app already exists in the context or database, use the existing instance
                    device.Apps.Remove(app);
                    device.Apps.Add(existingApp);
                }

                // If the app does not exist, it will be added as a new entity along with the new device
            }

            // Now add the new device with its apps
            _context.Devices.Add(device);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error while adding device {DeviceName} to the context: {Message}", device.DeviceName, e.Message);
            // Consider handling the exception based on your  application's needs
            // Do not rethrow the exception unless you have a specific reason to do so
            throw e;
        }
    }

    // Find and remove devices that are no longer in the devicelist
    var removedDevices = dbDevices.Where(db => !devicelist.Any(d => d.Id == db.Id)).ToList();
    _context.Devices.RemoveRange(removedDevices);
}

_logger.LogInformation("Save context");

var totalEntities = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count();
var processedEntities = 0;
int batchSize = 500;

while (processedEntities < totalEntities)
{
    // Process a batch of changes
    var batch = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                        .Skip(processedEntities)
                        .Take(batchSize)
                        .ToList();

    // If there are no more entities to process, break out of the loop
    if (!batch.Any())
    {
        break;
    }

    try
    {
        // Save the current batch
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Detach entities to free up memory
        foreach (var entry in batch)
        {
            _context.Entry(entry.Entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }

        // Update the number of processed entities
        processedEntities += batch.Count;

        // Log the progress
        _logger.LogInformation($"Saved batch: {processedEntities}/{totalEntities} entities processed.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception and decide how to handle it
        _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while saving a batch of changes.");
        // Depending on your requirements, you might choose to  break, continue, or retry
        break;
    }
}

I tried this code with a subset of devices and it seemed to work, so at least I thing it's working without any change tracking issue but it's way too slow to be usable. If someone could help me optimizing it it would be great !

Skip using EF an instead use SqlBulkCopy

The code is wrong, not EF. Besides, EF is an ORM, not a bulk import tool. The code itself is very slow, hitting the  database for every single object. If Devices is a DeviceModel DbSet, all you really need to do is context.UpdateRange(deviceList);. This will attach all items and their related entities, either in the Added or Modified state depending on their Id values. When context.SaveChanges(); is called EF will generate the necessary UPDATE or INSERT statements in the correct order. No reason to work with the change tracker or hit the database

Even if you really have to load the devices, it's faster to load them all at once with context.Devices.Where(d=>deviceIds.Contains(d.Id))

Thanks for answering. But I'm getting an issue when using _context.UpdateRange(deviceList). I'm getting the error : 'The instance of entity type 'DetectedAppModel' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{id:xx}' is already being tracked. Some DetectedAppModel might be associated with several devices
